# Woocommerce price in meta data

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using the WooCommerce plugin and I can't figure how to remove the meta price information. I'm trying to remove the price info from displaying when a product gets shared on Facebook and/or Twitter. The website does have Yoast SEO plugin also installed but I'm not seeing anyway to remove it. I have no price showed on the product page.

Does anyone know how to modify meta data information? I've found the meta customer information. Just not product.

**UPDATE**

Basically I want to remove this:

```
 <!-- Misc. tags -->
 <meta name="twitter:label1" content="Price"/>
 <meta name="twitter:data1" content="50 USD"/>
 <meta property="product:price:amount" content="50"/>
 <meta property="product:price:currency" content="USD"/>
 <meta property="product:availability" content="instock"/>
 <!-- is_singular | is_product -->
```

You can only see it when you do a view source. The Price gets shown whenever you copy and paste the link in any social media platform.

**LAST UPDATE**
It was the Open Graph Facebook plugin. View Kashif Rafique response below in the comments.

Comment: Better add some code ..less info

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla I really wasn't sure what to add code wise because I can't see what code is calling it. View the updated question for the code I want to remove that gets put in the front end.

Comment: how you are sharing? which page? woocommerce does not comes with share product feature..may be you can use javascript to remove it.

Comment: If you just copy and paste the URL for a variation product page in any social media site, it pulls the price from the meta description. We do have Yoast and WP Bakery Page Builder installed, but I tried to do a search in those plugin folders and never found anything regarding Woocommerce. Qcode is installed that came with the theme that had some Woocomerce customization but it looks to be just style stuff.

Comment: got any links to share?

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla sure! http://ilovebigbetty.com/product/big-betty-floats-wine-bottle-pool-floaty/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following filters available in Yoast WordPress SEO:

`apply_filters( 'wpseo_twitter_metatag_key', 'name' );`
[Source: wpseo_twitter_metatag_key](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/trunk/frontend/class-twitter.php#L154-L159)

`apply_filters( 'wpseo_og_' . $og_property, $content );`
[Source: wpseo_og_' . $og_property](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/trunk/frontend/class-opengraph.php#L72-L79)

**EDIT - Review after seeing the product URL**

Yoast SEO is not generating the Twitter/FB meta tags. [Open Graph for Facebook, Google+ and Twitter Card Tags](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wonderm00ns-simple-facebook-open-graph-tags/) plugin is responsible for rendering these meta tags.

Seems that plugin doesn't allow product level configuration for price. It offers few filters with the meta tags inserting function:

1. `fb_og_disable`
2. `fb_og_enabled`
3. `fb_og_output`

You would like to study the code and extend the plugin as per your need. A simple and easy solution is comment out or remove the responsible code from `wonderm00ns-simple-facebook-open-graph-tags/public/class-webdados-fb-open-graph-public.php` file, but it is not a recommended and future-safe way.

Comment: That was a great suggestion! I tried commenting out the returns and it's still in there.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd want. I just have a bunch of plugins. Here's a link to the product: http://ilovebigbetty.com/product/big-betty-floats-wine-bottle-pool-floaty/

Comment: Yoast SEO is not generating the Twitter/FB meta tags. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wonderm00ns-simple-facebook-open-graph-tags/ plugin is responsible for this.

Comment: That was totally it! Found it in public/class-webdados-fb-open-graph-public.php! I'm going to give your answer above the mark so you get the credit. THANKS!!!

Comment: @cbloss793 Seems that plugin doesn't allow product level configuration for price. It offers few filters with the meta tags inserting function `fb_og_disable`, `fb_og_enabled` and `fb_og_output`. You would like to study the code and extend the plugin as per your need. A simple and easy solution is comment/remove the responsible code from `wonderm00ns-simple-facebook-open-graph-tags/public/class-webdados-fb-open-graph-public.php`, but it is not a recommended and future-safe way.

Comment: @cbloss793 Glad to help you. Also updated my answer.

Comment: I saw there was no safe way to hide it. I just commented it out for now with the knowledge that it's gonna be overwritten if the plugin gets updated. :( Thanks for the feedback though!